# getUserMedia - image size

Tags: html, html5-video, getusermedia

I want to fill the div (#myvid) with the camera stream accessed by the iPhone, which I get from getUserMedida.

The image below shows the image stream on the MacBook.

My CSS looks like the following:

```
#myvid {
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 200px;
}
```

[image: Safari IOS]

[image: MacBook - Cam]

If I increase the size of #myvid (e.g. to 300px) the image will fill up the div) but is vertically too large.

The aim is to display the stream like on the mac-book on the mobile device

Answer (score 0):

```
object-fit: cover;
```

did the job.